# Same font on same browser appears different on different computers

Tags: fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

we are using the webfont "Rubik". On all our computers it is loading just fine. Except for one where it appears all janky. We are using the same version of Chrome (latest stable 66). The OS is the same Windows 10. This font also appears janky when we try it with Firefox. So the issue must be system related

Comment: Check in the debugger and see which font is *actually* being used. Then you'll know if it's a rendering issue or if your HTML/scripting isn't pulling in the correct font.

Comment: @TerryCarmen we checked the loaded fonts, and Rubik is indeed loading. We did another test, also. This computer had windows 7 installed, too. On windows 7 the bug is not present, only on Windows 10